# OSX: Put terminal window as tab in another one

Tags: macos, tabs, terminal, window

OSX (10.11, El Capitan)

Given a terminal window with multiple tabs, it is possible to drag a tab out of its window so that it becomes a new separate window.

Is it possible to put it back?

Comment: This is a question for [Apple.se]

Comment: @Thomas true, sorry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, just go under the Windows menu item and select "Merge All Windows".

Comment: this merges all windows. What if I can merge just two of them (if I have more than two open).

Comment: @Vincenzooo  The workaround is to merge all windows into a single window and then you can break out a single terminal window from the glob of windows

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method:

In order to marge the 2 windows, *both* windows must have 2 or more tabs:

1. **Add** a tab to the window that you 'pulled out'. (**Shell** > **New Tab**)

   - *(If the original window also has only 1 tab, add a tab to it, too.)*
2. Drag the desired tab back into the original window.
3. Close the extra window.

   - *(If you added an extra tab to the original window, you can close it, too.)*

---

**2023-01-14**: Updated, based on comments. Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Have you tested it? Have you left out some important details?

Comment: The original window must also have at least two tabs, for you to be able to drag a tab from another window into it. This means that you have to add a temporary dummy tab in the original window as well, if you do not already have tabs in it. Then you can drag in the new tab without problem. Why oh why do they make this so hard?